# How to show the X-axis date ticks neatly or in a form of certain interval in a plotly chart

Tags: python, charts, plotly, seaborn, ohlc

I am making an OHLC graph using plotly. I have stumbled across one issue. The labels in the x-axis is looking really messy . Is there a way to make it more neat. Or can we only show the extreme date values. For example only the first date value and last date value is show. The date range is a dynamic in nature. I am using the below query to make the graph . Thanks for the help.

```
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Candlestick(x=tickerDf.index.date,
                    open=tickerDf.Open,
                    high=tickerDf.High,
                    low=tickerDf.Low,
                    close=tickerDf.Close) )

    fig.update_xaxes(showticklabels=True )    #Disable xticks 
    fig.update_layout(width=800,height=600,xaxis=dict(type = "category") ) # hide dates with no values
    
    st.plotly_chart(fig)
```

Here tickerDf is the dataframe which contains the stock related data.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

One way that you can use is changing the `nticks`. This can be done by calling `fig.update_xaxes()` and passing `nticks` as the parameter. For example, here's a plot with the regular amount of ticks, with no change.
[image]

and here is what it looks like after specifying the number of ticks:
[image]

The code for the second plot:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('./finance-charts-apple.csv')

fig = go.Figure([go.Scatter(x=df['Date'], y=df['AAPL.High'])])

fig.update_xaxes(nticks=5)

fig.show()
```

the important line, again is:

```
fig.update_xaxes(nticks=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution

```
fig1.update_xaxes(type='category')
fig1.update_xaxes(nticks=12)
```

But thank you very much